# FullCalendar.io events not populating JSON from WebAPI MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, fullcalendar

I know there are a ton of posts on JSON not populating the FullCalendar.io events however, here I sit, frustrated and at my wits end. 
After reading through for hours(most of the afternoon actually) and following suggestions I found, along with a bit of trial and testing, I believe I have narrowed my issue down to a few possibilities.

Here is the rundown:

I have a WebAPI that uses MVC and is currently running locally as a test server (IISExpress from within Visual Studio 2017).  The WebAPI gets its data from a SQL server/Stored Procedure (which is not local to my matchine) and returns the data, which I put into a list and serialize as a JSON string via the Json.Net serializer.  Using both the browser and Postman, I am able to verify the data returned is a valid JSON string.  When I insert the JSON string (returned from the WebAPI) manually into FullCalendar it works fine, but when I ask FullCalendar to go and retrieve the data from the WebAPI it fails.

Here is the WebAPI code:

```
 public class CalData
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public DateTime start { get; set; }

    }

// GET api/values

    public string Get()
    {

        SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("My SQL Connect String");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader reader;

        cmd.CommandText = "GetData";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

        sqlConnection1.Open();

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        List<calData> CalInfo = new List<CalData>();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            CalData item = new CalData()
            {
                title = (string)reader["title"],
                start = (DateTime)reader["start"]

            };
            CalInfo.Add(item);
        }

        reader.Close();

        sqlConnection1.Close();

        string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(CalInfo);

        return output;


    }
```

Here is the JSON String it exports:

```
[{ 
  "title": "Test1",
  "start": "2018-04-12T00:00:00"
 },
 { 
   "title": "Test2",
   "start": "2018-04-13T00:00:00" 
}]
```

The calendar page is a "View" from an ASP.NET MVC.  Here is the code between the script tags with the JSON hard coded in, which as noted earlier works just fine:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({})

});


$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events:
        [{ 
         "title": "Test1", 
         "start": "2018-04-12T00:00:00" 
         },
         {
           "title": "Test2",
           "start": "2018-04-13T00:00:00"
          }]

     });
```

Now here is the code built from the documentation on the FullCalendar.io website:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({})

});


 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: 'http://localhost:51730/api/values'

});
```

I have verified FullCalendar is asking for the data by putting a breakpoint on the WebAPI (Yes I cleared the breakpoint afterwards and it still did not work!)  I am left to think one of two things is happening, (1)The API is too slow and FullCalendar is not waiting for the data. (2) There is a formatting issue when FullCalendar makes the call on its own.

I am new enough to C#, JQuery, and Visual Studio that I am not sure how to debug my FullCalendar MVC view to determine if the FullCalendar call is waiting for the data, as suspected in option 1 above.  Likewise, I am not sure to how to view what FullCalendar receives and does with the JSON string from my WebAPI for option 2. Therefore I am pretty much at an impasse.

I would very much appreciate some guidance here, I want to believe this has been an issue for someone else besides me, however, I have a feeling it is something simple I overlooked.  I also tried to provide as much information as possible, however if I need to add more please request it, I am happy to share whatever in hopes of resolving this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Change the method to `public List<CalData> Get()`, and `return CalcInfo;` (and don't hardcode in `http://localhost:51730` - it wont work as soon as you publish it)

Comment: Thank you, I made the changes you suggested and the WebAPI is pushing out JSON, however, the calendar still does not display of the events in the JSON.

Comment: Hmm, if the API really is outputting the JSON given in your sample above, then it should work perfectly. See http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/539/ - I just placed the same JSON at a sample URL (you can do the same at myjson.com) to act as an endpoint it the events display perfectly. So I would suggest either it isn't actually producing the correct JSON, or something else is amiss. Difficult to tell from your code above, which, in theory, works. Perhaps you have some other console / script error? Have you verified in your browser's network tools that the request to the API happens correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I finally was able to track down what the issue was thanks to some pointers from ADyson.  The issue was a Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) error that I discovered while inspecting the console in chrome.  Here is a screenshot of the error:
[CORS Error in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRs19.png)

The WebAPI and the ASP.Net MVC that is used for implementing my FullCalendar are both on the same machine however, since they each launch a version of IIS, the port numbers were naturally different.  By default the WebAPI is configured to only allow same domain/port requests as a security measure.  I found two links that helped me resolve the issue.  I am sharing them here, but please note in the first link (the video) the author uses * for the origin, which I would think that in any environment other than a test/dev would be unwise to use as it opens up your WebAPI to all origins and poses a potential security issue.  The second link (although a bit dated) explains in more detail how to allow CORS and what each piece of the code does.

Link 1: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uDy_cvf4nDg#action=share

Link 2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

I hope this helps someone else down the road. I am just happy I was not going crazy and my code was correct, it was just a permissions issue.

Many thanks to Stephan and ADyson for your input and guidance towards the answer.